# Jquery insertAfter() format?

Tags: jquery, insertafter

Is there a better way of writing this?

```
$('<span class="a"></span>').insertAfter($('#email'));
$('<span class="a"></span>').insertAfter($('#username'));
$('<span class="a"></span>').insertAfter($('#password'));
$('<span class="a"></span>').insertAfter($('#password_confirmation'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insertAfter can take a query string:

```
$("<span class=\"a\"></span>").insertAfter("#email,#username,#password,#password_confirmation")
```

Comment: This isn't working for me on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/4uXqa/1/) (Chrome).

Comment: @Hans that might have to do with the fact that it's an empty span tag. Try placing content inside of the span, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4uXqa/3/).

Comment: @Hans It got me the first time too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#email,#username,#password,#password_confirmation')
   .insert($('span').attr('class', 'a'));
```